# Array stuck in some sort of loop

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm in the process of making a program that asks for a user to input a 4 digit number and then have that number stored into an array. There are not to be repeated numbers, so I created a function that is to check if the user inputted duplicates. If they did, the function is supposed to return false, and if they did not the function returns true. My problem is that when I go to run the program, it will prompt the user to enter a 4 digit number, but then once they do, the program states that it is already in the system..
Here is the function:

```
bool isExist(int ssn, int record[], int number_of_records)
{
    if (record[ssn] < max_ssn && record[ssn] > min_ssn)
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_records; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i; j < number_of_records; j++)
            {
            if (record[i] == record[j])
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how I call it in main:

```
while (isExist)
    {
        cout << "Already in the system. Please enter a different social security number:\t";
        cin >> record[ssn];
        if (isExist == false)
        {   
            cout << "Enter another four digit social security number:\t";
            cin >> record[ssn];
        }
    }
```

Can someone help?

Comment: _"Can someone help?"_ Most certainly not. Post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.

Comment: `while (isExists)` This only checks that `isExists` is a non-NULL pointer. It does not actually call the function, let alone checking its return value. Did it not surprise you that, while the function is declared to take three parameters, you aren't passing any?

Answer (score 0):

In you while loop you look to be referring to a variable `isExist` which never gets set to `true`, you don't appear to be making a call to your method `isExist` and setting your local variable

Answer (score 0):

Your code never calls the `isExist` function. Try using it like this:

```
while (isExist(record[ssn], records, num_records))
    {
        cout << "Already in the system. Please enter a different social security number:\t";
        cin >> record[ssn];
        if (isExist == false)
        {   
            cout << "Enter another four digit social security number:\t";
            cin >> record[ssn];
        }
    }
```